# Grails ElasticSearch Plugin - Suggest Query

Tags: grails, elasticsearch, grails-plugin, search-suggestion

Is it possible to write a suggest query using the plugin?
There's nothing about that in the plugin documentation.
If it's possoble, how do I do that?

Here's the elasticsearch docs about suggest querys:
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters.html
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html

Thanks very mutch for the answer.

Comment: You may send direct http queries, get back JSON-answers and map them to the Domain classes.

Comment: thanks @wwarlock! could you some example of how do i do that?

Comment: Yes, I can, but I need some time, maybe at the nearest weekend.

Comment: I'm really sorry, still had no time to write this. But I'm not forgot about it.

Comment: i have seen that the plugin currently support suggestion. but performing an http query to elasticsearch is different approach and a workaround till the plugin doesnt support it. @SergioMendonça .. How are you handling it now?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you do need to send the query directly to Elastic Search. Below is the code I used:

```
import groovyx.net.http.ContentType
import groovyx.net.http.Method
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils
import org.apache.commons.lang.math.NumberUtils
import groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder
...

def suggestion = params.query

def http = new HTTPBuilder('http://localhost:9200/_suggest')
http.request(Method.POST, ContentType.JSON) {
    body = [
            'suggestion': [
                    'text': params.query,
                    'term': ["field": "_all"]
            ]
    ]

    response.success = { resp, json ->
        json?.suggestion?.each { s ->
            def oldWord = s?.text
            def newWord = s?.options[0]?.text ?: oldWord
            suggestion = StringUtils.replace(suggestion, oldWord, newWord)

        }
    }

    response.failure = { resp ->
        flash.error = "Request failed with status ${resp.status}"
    }
}
searchResult.suggestedQuery = suggestion
```

Note, that this is an excerpt. Additionally, I am performing the actual search, then appending the suggestedQuery attribute to the searchResult map.

Perform an HTTP POST to the _suggest service running with Elastic Search. In my example, this was a simple web application running on a single server, so localhost was fine. The format of the request is a JSON object based off of the Elastic Search [documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters.html).

We have two response handlers - one for success, another for errors. My success handler iterates over each word that a suggestion was given for and picks the best (first) suggestion for each one, if there is one. If you want to see the raw data, you can temporarily add in `println(json)`.

One last note - when adding the httpBuilder classes to the project you are likely to need to exclude a few artifacts that are already provided. Namely:

```
runtime('org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.5.1') {
    excludes 'xalan'
    excludes 'xml-apis'
    excludes 'groovy'
}
```